# Playing MIDI files in Totem on 13.10

Tags: 13.10, totem, midi

In previous versions of Ubuntu, playing MIDI files "just worked"; Totem would open and play them. However, ever since I upgraded to Saucy it can no longer do this; instead it generates an error about a missing plugin. I've heard of some command line workarounds, but is there any way to make it just work as it did in earlier versions?

Answer (score 5):

Totem plays MIDI files on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) since I installed the package `fluid-soundfont-gm`. The package requires about 150 MB disk space.

The VideoLAN wiki https://wiki.videolan.org/Midi and this forum post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146538&page=2 (answer by 
rubo77) recommend installing the package `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth`. The VLC package has `fluid-soundfont-gm` as a dependency, which is how I found `fluid-soundfont-gm`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the gstreamer0.10-codecs-bad package in the software centre which handles midi files ?  Generally on a new install I add the gstreamer good, bad and ugly codecs so that Totem can play almost everything I throw at it...

Comment: Yes, I already have that package installed.